# Как запушить все файлы на новый репозиторий?

Tags: git, сервер, github, vps, heroku

Я создал Git сервер у себя на vps. С ноута я могу отправлять на 2 сервака изменения (heroku, github). Добавил репо "server", коммитит норм, всё ок. Как теперь залить все файлы на новый репо? Не те, что изменились, а все сразу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

После того, как вы добавили новую удаленную репу с помощью `git remote add NEWREMOTE ....`, можно выполнить

```
git push NEWREMOTE --all
git push NEWREMOTE --tags
```

где `NEWREMOTE` - имя вашей новой удаленный репы.